# Div inside another div css?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs inside a parent div..i need the parent div to get bright on hover ..
Here is the fiddle..
i tried using hover, but couldnt get it...any help please

http://jsfiddle.net/d9yPK/

html:

```
  <div class="parent" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div class="one">
      <img class="img1" src="http://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/vincent- van-gogh-paintings-from-saint-remy-2.jpg"/>
    </div>
     <div class="two">
        <img class="img2" src="http://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/vincent-van-gogh-paintings-from-saint-remy-2.jpg"/>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Currently there is no css selector for parents: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector` you might need to use js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d9yPK/1/

Comment: i have this whole parent div in another div...what if i need to put position relative to the parent ? does that work

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have this in your CSS `.parent hover`. But it needs a `:` in between instead of a space, like so: `.parent:hover`.

Also remove the `style` attribute from the `parent` div. Just define a border in your CSS.

Now you should be able to use `hover` from your `parent` class: http://jsfiddle.net/d9yPK/4/

Comment: but..i have that parent div inside another div..i have position relative to the upper div..if i put relative this parent div is not visible..

Comment: This is because you only define the `border-color`. Without the inline style, you should define the type and width of the border in css. Just do `border: 1px solid blue;` on hover. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9yPK/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Move the inline style to the stylesheet:

```
<div class="parent"> <!-- remove style="border:1px solid black" -->
```

And change the CSS to:

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.parent:hover { /* you forgot the : here */
    border-color:blue;
}
```

[**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d9yPK/6/)